# Debug problems with PHP and MySQL [short]

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code and it is driving me crazy.

```
function getText($id){
 global $mysqli, $table_name;

 $sql = "SELECT `text` FROM $table_name WHERE `id` = $id;";
 if($result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    print $row["text"] . "<br>";
    return $row["text"];
 } else {
    printf("<br>" . $mysqli->error);
 }

 $result->free();
}
```

I get the error: **Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getText() in ... on line 50**

I also tried using one of these online error checkers and it printed out the same error when i paste just this function into their textbox. https://phpcodechecker.com/

Can anyone pls help me?

Comment: You have 2 or more functions with the same name (`getText`)

Comment: I don't that is the problem.. I even copy-pasted just this function into this https://phpcodechecker.com/ and it printed out the same error

Comment: Choose another name for `getText` then and you will see

Comment: It looks like [`gettext`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) is a function known to php, maybe call it differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gettext is a built-in function of PHP
(read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php)

This means that you are not allowed to make a function of your own with the same name.

Change the name of your function to something else and it will work.

Comment: this worked. I named it getTheText() xp. Will mark this as the correct answer as soon as it allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

functions in php aren't case-sensitive

You've likely collided with a built-in localization function `gettext()`. Even if this isn't the case your function should be renamed for portability's sake.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is causing because getText is built-in function in php, also there are few syntax errors in your function.

```
function getMyText($id){
 global $mysqli, $table_name;
 $sql = "SELECT `text` FROM $table_name WHERE `id` =".$id;
 $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
  if($result){
   $row = $result->fetch_array();
   print $row["text"] . "<br>";
   return $row["text"];
 } else {
   printf("<br>" . $mysqli->error);
 }
   $result->free();
}
```

Comment: Please never actually change a function's name to `getText1()` or something similar, it makes it a complete hell to use your code and would be thrown away in the blink of an eye. Change it to something more descriptive.

Comment: php allows you to use variables inside your string without having to split it so you can also do `"WHERE id = $id"` and it won't throw an error

Comment: I was just suggesting to change function name I'll edit my answer.